# Javascript error in getting values from checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I'm not able to get the value from my checkboxes when each of them is selected alone (i.e. in isolation), except for the last one which works fine.

Could anyone help me figure this out and correct my code?

```js
function showChoices() {
  var values = [];
  var cbs = document.catalog.colors;
  for (var i = 0, cbLen = cbs.length; i < cbLen; i++) {
    if (cbs[i].checked) {
      values.push(cbs[i].value);
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "You selected: " + values.join(', ') + ".";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "Please select an option.";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="catalog">
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="red" /><span>red</span> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="orange" /><span>orange</span> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="green" /><span>green</span> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue" /><span>blue</span> <br />
  <input type="button" onclick="showChoices();" value="Submit">
</form>

<br />
<span id='display'></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Working Solution

You can write js like this and hope this helps:

```js
function showChoices() {
  var values = [];
  var cbs = document.catalog.colors;
  var cbLen = cbs.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < cbLen; i++) {
    if (cbs[i].checked) {
      values.push(cbs[i].value);
    }
  }
  if (values.length != 0) {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "You selected: " + values.join(', ') + ".";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = "Please select an option.";
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="catalog">
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="red" /><span>red</span> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="orange" /><span>orange</span> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="green" /><span>green</span> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue" /><span>blue</span> <br />
  <input type="button" onclick="showChoices();" value="Submit">
</form>

<br />
<span id='display'></span>
```

Comment: This solution is definitely working and was the simplest too.

Comment: Really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the div#display's innerHTML with the "Please select an option..." text whenever the last iteration of your loop jumps into the else block (meaning the last box isn't checked).

I would check if at least one element is selected, and if not return early from your function. After that, you can simply display the values by joining them together.

```js
function showChoices() {
  var values = [];
  var cbs = Array.from(document.catalog.colors);
  let el = document.getElementById('display');
  let checked = cbs.filter(e => e.checked);
  if (!checked.length) {
    el.innerHTML = 'Please select at least one';
    return false;
  }
  
  el.innerHTML = `You selected ${checked.map(e => e.value).join(', ')}`;
  return false;  
}
```

```html
<form method="post" name="catalog">
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="red" /><span>red</span> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="orange" /><span>orange</span> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="green" /><span>green</span> <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue" /><span>blue</span> <br />
  <input type="button" onclick="showChoices();" value="Submit">
</form>

<br />
<span id='display'></span>
```

Comment: Your answer really helped me figure out my mistake in the coding. I tried this solution and it's definitely working.